# How to reload source files in golang dlv

Tags: go

I am using dlv to debug golang source code. Is there any command that reloads a program after modifying the source code? I have searched online and the dlv documentation but did not found anything on how to do that.

Any help will be appreciated.

environment : centos

Comment: What program you want to reload do you want to re-run the go file using go run.

Comment: a simple single file like  test.go  or  test binary file . like gdb can reload after source code modify.

Comment: Use `F5` short key after changing the code and see the output in vscode debug console.

Comment: i don't understand, for examle  , I have run  " dlv debug test.go" , how to reload file without dlv exit after  file have modified.  i use F5 in the dlv debug console and not have any influences.

Comment: Use it in the vscode where you have opened the file for modification.

Comment: my environment is centos  and editor is vim , so can do that in the terminal console?

Comment: Oh I get you should edit our question adding the information that you are using vim editor and centos. Because I was thinking you are using vscode as editor.

Comment: I'm sorry for not description clear about my Development environment, and have any method can do that in dlv debug mode in linux console .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delve currently does not have a way to reload the compiled code you are running while preserving your state like breakpoints and traces.  Probably the best thing you can do is use the "source" command in Delve.  For example, if you put a file called `debug.txt` in the local directory, you can add:

```
break foo.go:171
on 1 print myVar
```

..and back in `dlv debug`:

```
$ dlv debug
Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) source debug.txt
Breakpoint 1 set at 0x1b0f5e5 for /path/to/foo.MyFunction() ./foo.go:171
(dlv)
```

your configured breakpoints are loaded.

This isn't a perfect solution and I miss the gdb behavior, so I created a GitHub issue to start a discussion: https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/1551

Answer (score 0):

you can use [rebuild](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/cli/README.md#running-the-program) to recompile the source and restart the process.

```
Breakpoint 7 (enabled) at 0x0 for main.main.func3() ./main.go:25 (0)
Breakpoint 8 (enabled) at 0x0 for main.main.func3() ./main.go:28 (0)
```

If you set breakpoint by **location**, and modify the source code, the breakpoint might be invalidated. See addr `0x0`. From my experience, If I delete the nearby code, the breakpoint is gone.

Answer (score -1):

~~ guess you are looking for live code reloading like this ~~

~~ https://github.com/codegangsta/gin ~~

- 1 if you are looking to debug without exiting vim then:
  `:new | 0read ! dlv debug #` will do.
- 2 if you are looking to load the dlv mode constantly you can probably use tmux with split-pane. With one pane having vim and your file open and the other running dlv. *When you change your file in vim(in a pane) delve(in the companion pane) reloads this file for debugging*.
- 3 if you just want to run debug at the time of saving the file, prefix the first command with `autocmd BufWritePre Filetype go` and add that to your `virmc`.

If you are looking for some command that rebuilds your executable each time you make a change, I think you are in the wrong place, debugging is not meant to rebuild the executable. After you are done debugging, you can check your application and run the command(some variation of `go build` or some wrapper that calls it). To build your executable.

Comment: ~.~, I just want reload file within  dlv debug mode , and need not to exit .

Comment: maybe i not describe clear,  i  mean  dlv have any command like gdb "file" 
  command that can reload executable when my source code have changed. thanks again